# Chart label doesn't update after running resizing range' macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Power Point presentation which ~200 slides. Each slide have one chart, which data is updated monthly by a link to a master xlsx file. In order to not show empty values (future months) in the charts, I have to open the data editor (chart right click > Edit data...) of every chart and select the range until the current month.

I wrote a macro for it in Power Point:

```
Sub Refresh_slides()

For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

    Set ObjSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

    On Error Resume Next

        Set mychart = ObjSlide.Shapes("Chart 3").Chart
        mychart.Select
        mychart.ChartData.Activate
        Set wb = mychart.ChartData.Workbook
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

        Application.Run "Refresh_slides_AUX.xlsm!atual_slide"

        wb.Close True

Next

End Sub
```

`Refresh_slides_AUX.xlsm` is an auxiliary macro worksheet to select the correct range of each chart (necessary because Power Point VBA, as long as I know, don't have an option to do it):

```
Sub atual_slide()

Windows("Gráfico no Microsoft PowerPoint").Activate
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$I$23")
ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

It works fine, but even after the range is resized the chart label doesn't reflect this change in source data. How can I force the appearance of the chart label to update? Seems like something is missing between lines

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize Range("$A$1:$I$23")
```

and

```
 ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

like a "refresh" or "reset", but I can't figure it out...

Any ideas?

PS. By "label" I mean a data table (don't know how they call it in english) which is a label option in Office. Eg. below:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps using [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) to set your chart data source(s) can assist greatly here. Admittedly, this may be unrelated to your *true* question, but I thought it may avoid some VBA code.

Comment: Why close the `ActiveWindow`? What if you just did `Activesheet.Close SaveChanges:=True`.  I'm just thinking out loud, but wouldn't closing the active window close the excel instance? Or is it the same as `Activesheet` in this use?

Comment: Yeah @BruceWayne both `ActiveWindow` and `Activesheet` do the same here..